# How to inspect “older” messages from a topic from Confluent Control Center,

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-control-center

Can you tell me how to inspect "old" messages from a topic (from Confluent Control Center)?

I'm logged in and trying to inspect but i see only new messages?

It is possible?

Or can i use only ksql for it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If there's no option to set the starting offset for consumption, then the UI only displays a live view of currently incoming data.

Even in ksql you have to specify the property to start reading the beginning offsets of the topic